# How to use %ROWTYPE when inserting into Oracle table with identity column?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, identity-column, rowtype

I have an Oracle 12c database with a table containing an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id   NUMBER  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  bar  NUMBER
)
```

Now I want to insert into the table using PL/SQL. Since in practice the table has many columns, I use `%ROWTYPE`:

```
DECLARE
  x foo%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  x.bar := 3;
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES x;
END;
```

However, it give me this error:

> ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column 
>   ORA-06512: at line 5

Since it is very good for code readability and maintainability, I do not want to stop using `%ROWTYPE`. Since I under no circumstances want to allow anything but the automatically generated ID's I do not want to lift the `GENERATED ALWAYS` restriction.

[This](https://dnikiforov.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/12c-identity-column-in-plsql-record-type/) article suggests that the only way to be able to use `%ROWTYPE` is to switch to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL`. Is there no other way to fix this?

Comment: What is wrong with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Someone could insert their own `id`, that is not part of the sequence. I do not want to allow that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a view and insert there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_FOO AS
SELECT BAR -- all columns apart from virtual columns
FROM foo;

DECLARE
   x V_FOO%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   x.bar := 3;
   INSERT INTO V_FOO VALUES x;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Smart workaround! Would prefer to not need any extra objects, so I will wait a while before accepting and see what other ideas people have.

Comment: Well, if you don't like to create the view you could loop over `ALL_TAB_COLS` and do everything dynamically with Package [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF). However, you would have to write a lot of code and it would definitely be an overkill.

Comment: Good point Wernfried, not to mention how inefficient the resulting code would be.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can think of, since you're on 12c is to make the identity column `INVISIBLE`, like the code below.

The problem is that it makes getting a `%ROWTYPE` *with* the id a little more difficult, but it's doable.

Of course, it may also confuse other people using your table to not see a primary key!

I don't think I'd do this, but it *is* an answer to your question, for what that's worth.

```
DROP TABLE t;

CREATE TABLE t ( id number invisible generated always as identity, 
                 val varchar2(30));

insert into t (val) values ('A');                 

DECLARE

  record_without_id t%rowtype;
  CURSOR c_with_id IS SELECT t.id, t.* FROM t;
  record_with_id c_with_id%rowtype;

BEGIN
  record_without_id.val := 'C';
  INSERT INTO t VALUES record_without_id;

  -- If you want ID, you must select it explicitly
  SELECT id, t.* INTO record_with_id FROM t WHERE rownum = 1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(record_with_id.id || ', ' || record_with_id.val);
END;
/

SELECT id, val FROM t;
```

Comment: I agree that this might cause bigger problems further on than it solves. But I appreciate the idea anyway, for completeness. Always good to have all the options on the table.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a mix of former answers - using view with invisible identity column - is a optimal way to accomplish this task:

```
create table foo (id number generated always as identity primary key, memo varchar2 (32))
;
create or replace view fooview (id invisible, memo) as select * from foo
; 
<<my>> declare 
    r fooview%rowtype;   
    id number;
begin
    r.memo := 'first row';
    insert into fooview values r
    returning id into my.id
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ('inserted '||sql%rowcount||' row(s) id='||id);  
end;
/
```

> inserted 1 row(s) id=1